# Python Element Tree Writing to New File

Tags: python, xml, tree, element

Hi so I've been struggling with this and can't quite figure out why I'm getting errors. Trying to export just some basic XML into a new file, keeps giving me a TypeError. Below is a small sample of the code:

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
from xml.etree.ElementTree import SubElement
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


root = Element('QuoteWerksXML')
tree = ElementTree(root)
ver = SubElement(root, "AppVersionMajor")
ver.text = '5.1'

tree.write(open('person.xml', 'w'))
```

Comment: Please post the whole traceback.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [`ElementTree.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) method defaults to us-ascii encoding and as such expects a file opened for writing binary:

> The output is either a string (str) or binary (bytes). This is controlled by the encoding argument. If *encoding* is `"unicode"`, the output is a string; otherwise, it’s binary. Note that this may conflict with the type of *file* if it’s an open file object; make sure you do not try to write a string to a binary stream and vice versa.

So either open the file for writing in *binary mode*:

```
with open('person.xml', 'wb') as f:
    tree.write(f)
```

or open the file for writing in *text mode* and give `"unicode"` as *encoding*:

```
with open('person.xml', 'w') as f:
    tree.write(f, encoding='unicode')
```

or open the file for writing in *binary mode* and pass an explicit encoding:

```
with open('person.xml', 'wb') as f:
    tree.write(f, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: And if writing to standard output, you can use `tree.write(sys.stdout.buffer)`.

Comment: in my case encoding could not be 'unicode'. I had to change it to "UTF-8" instead

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a filename to `.write()` method, i.e. you don't have to open a file object, so you can bypass the problem in the OP altogether by the following:

```py
tree.write('person.xml')
```

On a side note, you can pass encoding, declaration, indentation (since Python 3.9) etc. as well.

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ElementTree(ET.XML('<QuoteWerksXML><AppVersionMajor>5.1</AppVersionMajor></QuoteWerksXML>'))
ET.indent(tree)
tree.write("person.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

creates a file that looks like the following:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<QuoteWerksXML>
  <AppVersionMajor>5.1</AppVersionMajor>
</QuoteWerksXML>
```