# How to write into a preexisting xml file while maintaining the structure?

Tags: python, xml, file-io

I am trying to write this error checker where if the file name already exists, the data is written into that file. Ideally I'd like the xml file to look like this:

```
<CONTACT_INFORMATION>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <name>John</name>
        <phone>1111111111</phone>
        <email>something@gmail.com</email>
    </DATA_RECORD>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <name>Jane</name>
        <phone>2222222222</phone>
        <email>otherthing@gmail.com</email>
    </DATA_RECORD>
</CONTACT_INFORMATION>
```

The files are named with with the name so these would be INFO_John.xml and INFO_Jane.xml

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
def information(listofdata):
    root = et.Element('CONTACT_INFORMATION')
    record = et.SubElement(root, 'DATA_RECORD')
    et.SubElement(record, "name").text = listofdata[0]
    et.SubElement(record, "phone").text = listofdata[1]
    et.SubElement(record, "email").text = listofdata[2]

    tree = et.ElementTree(root)
    if os.path.exists(f"PERSON_{collected_data[0]}.xml") == True:
        tree.write(f"INFO_{collected_data[0]}.xml")
    else:
        tree.write(f"INFO_{collected_data[0]}.xml")
```

However, this is just overriding the original INFO_John.xml and INFO_Jane.xml instead of writing into the files. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is appending the new data to the file, you can do it by providing a file object instead of a name to the write function, as the documentation states:

> Writes the element tree to a file, as XML. file is a file name, or a
>   file object opened for writing.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write

```
# ab for append binary, as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713184/python-element-tree-writing-to-new-file
file = open(f"INFO_{collected_data[0]}.xml", "ab")
tree.write(file)
```

But if you don't want to append and instead want to modify it, you will need to open the file, modify the structure and write again, overwriting the file with the new one. For example, say that I have a xml like this:

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor direction="E" name="Austria" />
        <neighbor direction="W" name="Switzerland" />
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor direction="N" name="Malaysia" />
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor direction="W" name="Costa Rica" />
        <neighbor direction="E" name="Colombia" />
    </country>
</data>
```

If your intention is adding a new country, you will have to open that file, add a new country to the tree and overwrite the file. The first solution will literally append the new data, disregarding the root. You can also use the first approach and delete the root element before doing it. When your processing is done, you add again the root element.

[Edit]

If your intention is like adding a new country in my example, one way to do that is by opening the file and adding the new element to the other tree.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

tree = ET.parse('country.xml')
name = ''

# For all country at the tree
for country in tree.findall('country'):
    # If country has no attribute name, skip
    try:
        name = country.attrib['name']
    except TypeError:
        continue

    # File name format
    file_name = '{}.xml'.format(name)

    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        # File exists, open it
        temp = ET.parse(file_name)
        root = temp.getroot()

        # Preserving identation
        root[-1].tail = '\n    '
    else:
        # File doesn't exist, create new xml tree
        root = ET.Element('data')
        temp = ET.ElementTree(root)
        root = temp.getroot()

        # Preserving identation
        root.text = '\n    '

    # Put the country in the tree
    root.append(country)

    # Preserving identation
    country.tail = '\n'

    temp.write(file_name)
```

[EDIT 2]

Using the example of your answer, instead of doing something like this:

```
 try:
     name = country.attrib['name']
 except TypeError:
     continue
```

You will do something like this:

```
try:
    name = country.find('name').text
except TypeError:
    continue
```

Find name will find the first child tag named 'name' and return it. Text will get its contents. If the xml isn't well formed, it may not have a tag name, in this case, it will throw a 'TypeError', so we skip the iteration.

Here is a version with if-else:

```
if country.find('name') == None:
    continue

name = country.find('name').text
```

If you are sure that your xml is well formed, you can do this part as simples as:

```
name = country.find('name').text
```

You don't need to modify the rest of the code, only this part of the try-catch.

Comment: my intention is to add a new country, how do I append without overwriting the file (I don't want to lose the first country)?

Comment: would you mind explaining your try/except clause? Sorry but I don't have much experience with try/except. What does it do exactly? additionally, the variable country comes from the iterator in this try/except phrase, right?

Comment: Additionally, the xml file I am working with does not have any attributes, so that might be part of my confusion in the try/except clause (in my question I have an example of the xml file I'm working with)

Comment: Hey, about the try catch it works like this: it may be possible to the country not have an attribute, in this case, it will raise a TypeError exception, if it does, then we skip the loop with a continue and we go to the next iteration. If not, the name was given by the attribute in this example.

Comment: About the name attribute, yes, it comes from the try catch, because it can raise an exception. I could first check whether country has name, and it doesn't, we do nothing, if it has, we do the rest after the try-catch.

Comment: I will update the answer with a case similar to your question.