# How to close an xml file after overwriting an attribute in python

Tags: python, xml, file

I want to change an attributes value in an xmlfile, from 0 to 1 or vice versa. I have two methods of writing to an xmlfile, the first (xml_to_bin) leaves the file open and the second (xml_to_bin2) seems to remove all the contents of the xmlfile and gives a long traceback.

I need to be able to access the xml file many times in a test so when I save a value and have to reread that value later I need to know it has been changed and saved.

I have seen two similar questions, one helped me get this far.

**Code**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import time

if __name__ != "__main__": #for when this module is imported
    DropWatch = None

def get_bin_gs_xml_setting(xmlfile_path):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    isBinary = None
    #ET.dump(tree)# prints the xml file to console,shows xml indentation
    print('\n')
    for elm in root.findall("./Common/ForceToBinary"):
        #print('Initial XML file setting :', elm.attrib)
        if elm.attrib == {'type': 'integer', 'value': '1'}:
            print('unit SET TO 1 (BINARY)')
            isBinary = True
        elif elm.attrib == {'type': 'integer', 'value': '0'}:
            print('unit SET TO 0 (GREYSCALE)')
            isBinary = False
    return isBinary     
 


def xml_to_bin(xmlfile_path):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for elm in root.findall("./Common/ForceToBinary"):
        if elm.attrib == {'type': 'integer', 'value': '0'}:
            time.sleep(1.0)
            elm.attrib = {'type': 'integer', 'value': '1'}
            time.sleep(1.0)
    tree.write(xmlfile_path, xml_declaration=True, method='xml', encoding='UTF-8')
    print('xml file has had USB/Common/ForceToBinary value changed to BINARY.')



def xml_to_bin2(xmlfile_path):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for elm in root.findall("./Common/ForceToBinary"):
        if elm.attrib == {'type': 'integer', 'value': '0'}:
            time.sleep(1.0)
            elm.attrib = {'type': 'integer', 'value': '1'}
            time.sleep(1.0)
        with open(xmlfile_path, 'w') as filey:
            tree.write(filey, xml_declaration=True, method='xml', encoding='UTF-8')

#USING THE FUNCTIONS
if __name__ == "__main__":
    xmlfile_path = (r'C:\...\USB_TEST_04.XML')
    is_unit_binary = get_bin_gs_xml_setting(xmlfile_path)
    print("Is unit binary : ", is_unit_binary)
    if is_unit_binary is False:
        xml_to_bin2(xmlfile_path)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(get_bin_gs_xml_setting(xmlfile_path))

    is_unit_binary = get_bin_gs_xml_setting(xmlfile_path)
    print("Is unit binary : ", is_unit_binary)
```

**xml file**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<USB>
  <Common>
    <ForceToBinary type="integer" value="0" />
    <GuardValue type="integer" value="0" />
  </Common>
</USB>
```

**Traceback when running xml_to_bin2**

```
The script terminated with an unhandled error.

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
File line...
    xml_to_bin2(xmlfile_path)
File xml_to_bin2...
    tree.write(filey, xml_declaration=True, method='xml', encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713184/python-element-tree-writing-to-new-file

Comment: Thanks balderman, that was the question I found useful and helped me get this far.

Comment: did you try `with open(xmlfile_path, 'wb')` ?