# Finding and saving found element to new file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Currently I'm facing problem, where I have lot of large xml files, which contains 2 types of elements distinguished by specific child attribute.

I'm currently able to find and delete unwanted elements, after searching trough tree for that specific attribute and saving modified file. This takes too much time, as unwanted Elements makes as much as 90% of data to handled.

I realized that there must be a way, to instead of deleting unwanted elements, I can just find and copy WANTED elements to a new file and thus extract small amount of data almost the same way, just reverse logic.

My current code for searching, deleting and saving file looks as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open(file_name + ".xml", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as content:

    tree = ET.parse(content)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for findVesta in root.findall("./{n0}TicketFile"):
        for findTick in findVesta.findall("./{n0}Tick"):
            for findSC in findTick.findall("./{n0}SC"):
                for findGRC in findSC.findall("./{n0}GrcResAll"):
                    findVesta.remove(findTick)
    tree.write(file_name + ".xml")
```

I'm struggling to find way to instead of using .remove - to use a some kind of method to "copy to new file" or "append an existing file" with whole element findTick and its children , instead of removing it. I can easily alter it to look for actual attribute later.

In excel it would be simply copying whole row to a new file, after finding GrcResAll in that row.

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks.

Comment: did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713184/python-element-tree-writing-to-new-file)?

Comment: Hello, thanks, i did not. I still cant figure out how after last "for", write the whole element and children "findTick" to a new file.
I tried
'''
tree.write(open("moje.csv", "wb"))
'''
But that's a stretch, its just writing the file as it is, as i dont have a way to use element findTick only, identified trough those for iterations :/